# Converting circular structure to JSON: Angular2

Tags: angular

I have the following object:

```
someObj = {
  someVar: new FormControl(),
  index: 100,
  array1: [],
  array2: [],
  array3: [],
  array4: []
}
```

and I'm trying to store this in session storage. For that, I need to use

```
JSON.stringify(this.someObj);
```

but I get an error saying:

```
core.es5.js:1084 ERROR TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

After doing some research I found that the error is because I have a formControl in my object. Doing something like this,

```
JSON.stringify(this.someObj.searchTerm.value);
```

won't give an error. But I want to convert the whole object into string representation. I can obviously pass all the individual object elements one by one with JSON stringify but thats not an efficient solution.
Can somebody suggest a workaround?

Comment: JSON can not have circular references.

Comment: If you don't want to stringify the form control, you can use the replacer function in JSON.stringify and return undefined when the type is "someVar"

Comment: If you don't think JSON can have circular references then you've never tried to stringify an expressjs request before :)

Comment: 'But I want to convert the whole object into string representation' Is it means you want to convert your FromControl to JSON? Why? This is not a good design, and you will not be able to do that.